# C# Find a Method by Name and run it (IEnumerator method)

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to retrieve & run a function inside some other object according to it's name.

So, for example, given the following class:

```cs
public class A 
{
    public IEnumerator func1()
    {
        print("function 1");
        yield break;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve **func1** and run it.

My Attempt:

```cs
public static MethodInfo GetMethodByName(object obj, string methodName)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == methodName);
}
```

then:

`Startcoroutine((IEnumerator)GetMethodByName(classAObject, "func1"));`

***ERROR I GET:***

**"Specified cast is not valid"**

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to cast a `MethodInfo` to a `IEnumerator`. You probably want to call [MethodInfo.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=net-5.0) and cast the result, i.e.

```
(IEnumerator)(GetMethodByName(classAObject, "func1").Invoke(classAObject, null)))
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working!

However, I'm not too sure why. I thought invoking ienumerators simply runs them



*I forgot to mention that I'm intending to store the ienumerator in a variable for a later use

Comment: @go fast you are not invoking the ienumerator, you are invoking the MethodInfo, i.e. calling 'func1' thru reflection.